# Simple MVVM - how to notice propertychange between two viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, i wrote this code:

xaml1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Aplikacja_desktopowa.CustomerView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="150" Width="300" 
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomerViewModel}">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Command="{Binding LogowanieCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Button"  IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Xaml2:

```
<Window x:Class="Aplikacja_desktopowa.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Aplikacja_desktopowa"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=[MainPageViewModel]}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BannerText}" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Content="Button" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomerViewModel.IsEnabled}"/>
        <my:CustomerView />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

View Model with property

```
public class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged{
    private DelegateCommand _przycisk;
    public ICommand LogowanieCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_przycisk == null)
                _przycisk = new DelegateCommand(funkcja1, funkcja2);
            return _przycisk;
        }
    }

    public void funkcja1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Odblokowywanie przycisku");
        IsEnabled = true;
    }
    public bool funkcja2()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            _isEnabled = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

It is something like this:

```
view1 ({binding IsEnabled) ----- view_model1_with_property_IsEnabled 
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |
main_view ( with Staticresource view_model1,IsEnabled)
```

I tried everything, but its not working ;((

How to notice propertychanged in both xamls?

#### Question clarification

Ok, so, i have two separate viewmodels, two separate views in wfp ( simple mvvm template ) When i click at button, it will set property IsEnabled at true. Its ok, notifypropertychange is working. But when i wanna notify property in different view ( for example i want unlock button in view1 when i click button in view2 )

```
<Button Content="Button" IsEnabled="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, 
Path=CustomerViewModel.IsEnabled}"/>
```

it isnt, working ;( I looking for the easiest way to make sth like this in simple mvvm

---

Sheridan, i made a property in ViewModelLocator and its working, like i wanted, thx ... but when im implementing bigger application, in ViewModelLocator i will get a lot of methods, is there nicer solution ?

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly... *much* more clearly.

Comment: I meant for you to describe your problem more clearly *in your question*... I have copied your comment there so that it is clear to everyone.

Comment: @user3045261 Now delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a look at using a framework like galasoft's mvvm light, it provides  a messaging class that lets you pass objects between view models.

[MVVM Light Messenger - Sending and Registering Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993918/mvvm-light-messenger-sending-and-registering-objects)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this problem, but one of them is to use a parent view model that has access to the other view models. The simplest fix would be to define your `bool IsEnabled` property in the parent view model and then to bind directly to this property from the two child view models:

```
<Button Content="Button" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsEnabled, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourParentView}}}" />
```

This `RelativeSource Binding` will look for a property named `IsEnabled` in the object that is set as the `DataContext` of a parent or ancestor of this `Button` control of type `YourParentView`. Obviously, you'll need to update the names to those in your code.