# MVVM - calling UI-logic in code behind from ViewModel

Tags: xaml, events, mvvm, viewmodel, code-behind

I'm working on some .Net XAML application using MVVM pattern.
According to MVVM I keep my app logic in VM and in Code Behind I do UI-related actions.
But I need to execute some UI-related code in Code Behind in respond to some logic in VM.

Example:
I need to show an error message (custom toast notification in my case) when login operation failed. Login operation resides in VM, but I can't use any UI-specific classes in my VM, so I made an event in VM and hooking up to in in Code Behind, doing UI stuff.

Is it a violation of MVVM pattern? If yes, then how to solve my case?

Comment: Do not do anything in code behind. You can bind nearly everything (for some things it is complex). Either it is button click, combobox selection changed.

Comment: And try to add some code.

Comment: please show us the relevant code you are talking about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally communication between View and ViewModel in MVVM pattern done through [Mediator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern) to avoid hard-referencing View from VM. Having a mediator,

1. View can subscribe to certain type of message.
2. Then VM send the message to mediator,
3. mediator broadcast the message, so all party that subscribed will get it.
4. Upon receiving, View can respond by executing certain UI logic according to the message

The CodeProject link above shows how to implement a mediator class. But I will suggest to use a [popular MVVM framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069883/2998271) since you'll find it has Mediator implementation and many other tools for MVVM available out-of-the-box.

Comment: if you chose MVVMLight framework, you can see how simple subscribe and sending message through Messenger (class name for mediator implementation in MVVMlight) in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16993918/2998271)

Comment: Thx, I'll read about mediator, but in case of using VM events there is no hard links to View. VM doesn't care who is exactly hooked up to the event, so event mechanism is some sort of simple built in mediator here?

Comment: sorry fixed the link.

Comment: So far I see Mediator is more common and save approach. For simple application using VM event approach maybe acceptable and save. But for more complex scenario we should be careful, because that approach will prevent View from being garbage-collected since there is reference to View from VM event. In case of using Mediator, it won't prevent subscribing parties from being garbage-collected [[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173630/MVVM-sharp-Episode-2)]

Comment: another advantage is, Mediator also applicable for VM-to-VM communication in case we want to avoid having reference from one VM to another. In short Mediator help us to avoid having reference from one class to another but still enable us to communicate between them *IN SAVE, WEAK-REFERENCE WAY*