# WPF MVVM Light Navigation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm working on a windows WPF application using MVVM Light. As far as for switching views and navigation purposes, is there set classes readily available?
Right now, I'm using a MainViewController to load other views with datatemplate and messenger class. But i'm not sure if its the best practice.

Comment: Why not use the MvvmLight Messenger for that?

Comment: how will the messenger be used? just to trigger calls and load the right controller in the main controller?

Comment: @my779 you seem to be on the right track. messenger also allows calls to be "directed" because of the subscription/broadcast concept. An answer with some actual code can be found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26266708/3109213

Comment: try to implement the Navigation Service to suit your needs, take a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966819/mvvm-light-5-0-how-to-use-the-navigation-service/28968560#28968560

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF MVVM navigate views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views)

Answer (score 0):

Meant for switching is ***ContentControl*** but it has nothing to do with MVVM Light. Based on its Content you can assign diffrent Views. Take a look [here](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/).

Comment: what if the sub view controllers has their own sub views? Such as a detail view from one of the view controllers. Will the MVVM light messenger framework be needed to trigger the change in the content control?

Comment: Presumably yes but you would have to paste some code to find out.