# Need assistance with making a button in one UserControl update the GUI in another UserControl using Properties in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to code a program where if you click on either a listbox item or a button in one usercontrol, it will update a textbox in another usercontrol.
I can't seem to figure out how to get this working properly with dependencyproperties.

**Listbox.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestDP3.ListBoxUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDP3">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="144" Margin="21,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"/>

    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,272,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyDp.Result}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

**VnInfo.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestDP3.VnInfoUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDP3">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,102,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DependencyProperty is: " VerticalAlignment="Top"/>    
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159,102,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyDp.Result, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MyDP _myDP;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            _myDP = new MyDP();

            TestCommand = new MyCommand(SampleMethod);

        }

        public MyDP MyDp
        {
            get { return _myDP; }
            set
            {
                _myDP = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyDP");              
            }
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }

        private int counter = 0;
        private int SampleMethod()
        {
            MyDp.Result = counter++;
            return MyDp.Result;  
        }
    }
```

**MyDP.cs**

```csharp
public class MyDP : DependencyObject
    {
        public int Result
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ResultProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ResultProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Result", typeof(int), typeof(MyDP) ,new PropertyMetadata(0) 
            );        
    }
```

Here is a link to the visual studio project:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22398345/TestDP.zip

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with WPF and MVVM, but I've never toyed with setting the DataContext in the xaml. Is <local:MyViewModel/> in each xaml file actually referencing the same object or is this call creating an all new object?

Comment: You are not doing right, it is not possible in this way, if you are using an mvvm framework try to use a messenger to send events between view models. Here is an example of mvvm light messenger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993918/mvvm-light-messenger-sending-and-registering-objects

Answer (score 0):

Both views must access the same object (ViewModel). I suspect your calls to

```
<local:MyViewModel/>
```

in each of the Xaml files are creating separate objects. You'll need to create a single MyViewModel object in your code-behind somewhere:

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
```

and pass a reference of it to each of the views, either through the constructor:

```
ListBoxUserControl(MyViewModel vm) { ... }
```

or to a property:

```
ListBoxUserControl.MyViewModel = vm;
```

Then you can then set your DataContext in the code-behind:

```
this.DataContext = vm;
```