# Changing View from ViewModel in View-Base WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am developing a view-based application using the MVVM-Light framework (C#). Essentially, I have a single window that opens with a content controller, and the view models determine which view is in the content controller.

I would like to run commands from each individual view model that changes the view. For instance, if the user were to press "Submit", the application would take them back to the main view.

The only thing I can think of is to have each view model require a ParentWindow argument of type `Window` in order to link back to the `CurrentViewModel` variable in my `MainWindowViewModel`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `CurrentViewModel` could have an event that the main window listens to.  Would be easy if all the `CurrentViewModel` types inherited from a base already

Comment: I think the better way is to not even think of putting any reference of a view  inside any of your ViewModel. You can achieve this by means of utilizing the DataTemplate with the list of your ViewModels. And then you probably need a SelectedItem property for binding and/or shifting from one view to another.

Comment: @Jonesopolis what do you mean by that? Could you expand a little?

Comment: @tgpdyk I need to update the current view model that is linked to the `ContentControl` so that I can have custom menus in each view, especially the `MainViewModel` (versus the `MainWindowViewModel`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MVVM Light` there is a feature called `Messenger`. You could use this to communicate between `ViewModel`s.

Here is an answer with an example of that: [MVVM Light Messenger - Sending and Registering Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993918/mvvm-light-messenger-sending-and-registering-objects)