# Using MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger to instantiate new View + ViewModel (Window)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have my `MainView` and an associated `MainViewViewModel` which are linked by `ViewModelLocator`.

Within `MainViewViewModel` there is a command which should trigger a new `Window` to open which has it's own View and ViewModel (`NewView` and `NewViewViewModel`).

In a lot of the examples I've seen it is suggested to use Mvvmlight's `Messenger` to do something like this:

```cs
public class MainViewViewModel
{

    private void OpenNewWindow()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("NewView"));
    }

}
```

And then register the `NewViewViewModel` and handle the message like this:

```cs
public class NewViewViewModel
{
   public NewViewViewModel()
   {
       Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
   }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage obj)
    {
         if (obj.Notification == "NewView")
         {
             NewView view = new NewView();
             view.Show();
         }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because the NewViewViewModel isn't yet instantiated (so isn't registered with `Messenger`). Additionally, this doesn't fit with MVVM because `NewViewViewModel` is responsible for creating `NewView`.

What is the correct way to achieve a simple command which instantiates and opens a new View and ViewModel pair which are linked via `ViewModelLocator` and setting of `DataContext="{Binding NewView, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` in `NewView.xml`?

Comment: Why is viewmodellocator part of the answer?  Reason I ask is there are other options. For example why not send the viewmodel instance and type of view in a message? Subscribe in mainwindow. In mainwindow you could instantiate the window. set datacontext to the viewmodel and show the window.

Comment: "In mainwindow you could instantiate the window." - This is what I'm learning towards as every other solution seems overly complicated, however this doesn't follow the MVVM architecture because a ViewModel is responsible for creating Views.

Comment: The code in mainwindow would be creating the view. But.... The whole idea of the pattern is to make things easier. It's not an end to itself. So I wouldn't worry too much about whether this breaks any abstract architectural pattern. BTW. I recommended passing an instance of a viewmodel because that then allows you to resolve any dependencies or pass in parameters or whatever you like from the "calling "viewmodel.

Answer (score 3):

Use a window service:

[MVVM show new window from VM when seperated projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352870/mvvm-show-new-window-from-vm-when-seperated-projects/47353136#47353136)

You may either inject the view model to with an `IWindowService` implementation or use a static `WindowService` class:

```
public static class WindowService
{
    public static void OpenWindow()
    {
        NewView view = new NewView();
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

Dependency injection is obviously preferable for being able to unit test the view model(s) and switch implementations of `IWindowService` at runtime.

Comment: I must be missing something, but to what namespace does IWindowService belong? I can't find it.

Comment: You need to define it yourself. Follow the link in my answer...

Comment: I did read that but all I see is WindowService implemented like this: `public class WindowService : IWindowService` where is IWindowService defined?

Comment: @WSC: It's just an interface that you need to define: `public interface IWindowService { void OpenProfileWindow(AddProfileViewModel vm); }`