# Change a value from a view model from another view model in MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two View Models, MainMenuViewModel and ListViewModel. MainMenuViewModel has the property `Page` which is a string with the name of a xaml file to change the `Source` of a `Frame`. Now I want to change this property from the ListViewModel. I'm not using any framework.
What I'm doing right now is to create a variable `public MainMenuViewModel mmvm { get; set; }` and calling a method from this variable to change the `Page` value, but is throwing `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. 
 How can I do this?

Comment: Fire up your debugger and figure out why it is null. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/324260.

Comment: How are you instantiating the `ListViewModel`? Please edit your question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

1. If `MainViewModel` and `ListViewModel` have a direct relationship, you can just pass a reference to `MainViewModel` when constructing `ListViewModel`. Then just call `MainViewModel's` property directly from `ListViewModel`.
2. If they don't have a direct relationship, you can use the Messenger pattern. Basically, `MainViewModel` will register to a type of message (e.g `ChangePageMessage`) and then `ListViewModel` will send an instance of that message to change the page. I don't know which MVVM framework you use but here's an [example for MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16993918/324260).

Comment: Im creating a MainMenuViewModel type variable in the ListViewModel for call a method inside MainMenuViewModel to change the value,but is not working. I described it in the post.

Comment: Fire up your debugger and figure out why it is null. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/324260. My best guess is you are not setting the `mmvm` property.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not initializing the variable, just declaring it. How can I initialize it in a way it listen to the change from ListViewModel?